# Ajax POST not sending data when calling 'request.POST' in Django view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I am attempting to get an Ajax `POST` to to send data to my view so I can manipulate my data there, when I click on a `div` with class `up-arrow`.

Problem is, when I click said div and print `request.POST` in my view file, I am getting a `POST` object that contains `<QueryDict: {}>`. Empty! I can't seem to figure out why my the POST request isn't sending my data through.

***Here is my HTML...***

```
{% for i in post.posts %}
    <li>
        <div>
            <div class='up-arrow'>
            </div>
            {{i}}
        </div>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

***Here is my AJAX/jQuery...***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.up-arrow').click(function(){
                $(this).hide()
                console.log('click')
                $.ajax({
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type':'application/json',
                        'X-CSRFToken': getCookie('csrftoken')
                    },
                    url: 'voteuppost',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {'dane': 123456789101112},
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert('success!')   
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        alert('fail')
                    }

                })
                return false
            });
            function getCookie(name) {
            var cookieValue = null;
            if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
                var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                    var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                    if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return cookieValue;
        }
        })
```

***Here is my view...***

```
class VoteUpPost(View):
    def post(self, request):
        print(request.POST)
        return JsonResponse({'status': True})
```

***Here is my url route...***

```
    url(r'^voteuppost$', VoteUpPost.as_view()),
```

***Things I have tried...***

1) I used `GET` instead of `POST` and I am able to get the data value using `request.GET.get('dane')`

1) Tried using `request.POST.data` and `request.POST.DATA` and get the following... `AttributeError: 'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'data'`
 and I also get a 'fail' `alert`.

How do I send my data over to my view via a `POST` request and then access the data within?

Comment: can you view what is contained in the post request through the developper tools? under the network tab

Comment: Did you try `JSON.stringify({'dane': 123456789101112})`? When passing JSON, it has to be a string. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32570523/why-when-sending-data-over-ajax-do-you-have-to-json-stringify-your-objects This may not be your issue, but something to consider.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When posting JSON data with `application/json` you need to use `request.body` instead of `request.POST`.

Like so:

```
class VoteUpPost(View):
    def post(self, request):
        print(request.body)
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        return JsonResponse({'status': True})
```

Also as Jacques mentioned, make sure to update your js to pass a JSON string.

Change:

```
data: {'dane': 123456789101112},
```

To:

```
data: JSON.stringify({'dane': 123456789101112}),
```

Comment: Thanks Paulo, you nailed it!

Comment: When I `print(request.body)` I am getting `b'dane=123456789101112'`. How do I access the `123456789101112`?

Comment: Updated my answer. Basically you need to make sure that data is a string.

Comment: when I do that, I get `b'{"dane":123456789101112}'`, but cannot access the value using the key. I have tried both `request.body.dane` and `request.body['dane']`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes you need to load it into json. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 8):

Django request can only parse **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** and 
**multipart/form-data** to `request.POST`. For other content types you have to use `request.body` property. for assertion of content type you can get the content type from `request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE')`

```
def sample_view(request):
    if request.META.get('CONTENT-TYPE') == 'application/json':
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        return JsonResponse({'any-message':'Hello'})
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I didn't give you the answer because a more concise answer was listed above. I gave you an upvote because you explained what Paulo didn't.