# Request of dictionary keeps coming in as Str, how can I get it to pass through as a dictionary?

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django, django-rest-framework

Hi I made an http POST and it keeps receiving as a string. I am trying to get it as a dictionary so I can pull each key, value.

I have my `$http.post('/route/', data).success({console.log("succes")}}`

My data:

```
    var data ={}

    data['company'] = user.user.company_name
    data['farmer'] = user.farmer
    data['number'] = "+14087729399"
```

Then from my views:

```
def initiate_sms(request):
    user_data = request.body
    print user_data
```

And would print as:

`{"company":"AkshaYagna","farmer":"Child.farm 06","number":"+14087729399"}`

Declaring that the whole thing is a string. I feel like I am missing something here.

Comment: `json.loads(user_data)`?

Comment: @Andy Can you add the output of ***`print(type(user_data))`*** ?

Answer (score 0):

[request.body](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.body) returns byte string. So you can use [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) function, for example:

```
import json

def initiate_sms(request):
    user_data = request.body
    user_data = json.loads(user_data)
    print(user_data)
```

Comment: I think question is about getting argument request as dictionary directly, instead of getting it as str and parsing to dictionary.

Comment: I don't think there is good way to do that unless using DRF. Checkout here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34533451/2696165