# xhr.send() post request don't pass data

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, django-react

on the typescript side, i have this code that should send post request.
note that `getCookie` function is copied from Django docs exactly like it is.

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.responseType = "json";
  xhr.open("POST", `http://localhost:8000/create/`);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  const coockie = getCookie("csrftoken");
  if (coockie) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH", "XMLHttpRequest");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-with", "XMLHttpRequest");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", coockie);
  }
  xhr.onload = function () {
    callback(xhr.response, xhr.status);
  };
  xhr.onerror = function (e) {
    console.log(e);
    callback({ message: "The request was an error" }, 400);
  };
  xhr.send('{"content":"new text"}');
```

in views.py

```
@api_view(["POST"])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def post_create_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    print(request.data)
    serializer = CreateTweeSerializers(data={request.data})
    # raise_exception= if form.error reutnr error and status400
    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        serializer.save(user=request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=201)
    return Response({}, status=400)
```

```
`print(request.data)` or `print(request.POST)` return `<QueryDict: {}>`
```

Comment: can you try request.post ? or print request ?

Comment: yes it is the same

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532573/ajax-post-not-sending-data-when-calling-request-post-in-django-view you should try request.body and maybe change your '{"content":"new text"}'

Comment: Can i post the answer and get the points ? ;)

Answer (score 0):

use `request.body` instead of `request.data`
and instead of `data={request.data}` use `json.loads(request.body)`

```
import json
    print(request.body)
    serializer = CreateTweeSerializers(data=json.loads(request.body))
```