# checkbox value not getting posted in Views.py Django

Tags: python, django, ajax, post

i have code which should post values of selected checkbox to Views.py after a button click ,
but for me it is sending me an empty list when trying to print the checkbox value in views.py

So below is my code .

Views.py

```
if request.method=='POST':
       if 'submit' in request.POST:
           user_list = request.POST.getlist('myarray')
           print(user_list)
```

html

```
  <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                                  <!-- <div class="w-full sm:w-auto flex items-center sm:ml-auto mt-3 sm:mt-0">
                                      <label class="form-check-label ml-0 sm:ml-2" for="show-example-5">Show Server List</label>
                                      <input data-target="#document-editor" class="show-code form-check-switch mr-0 ml-3" type="checkbox" id="show-example-5">
                                  </div> -->
                                  <button id= "AnchroTagForButton" name="submit" href="">
                                    <span></span>
                                    <span></span>
                                    <span></span>
                                    <span></span>
                                    button
                                </button>
                              </div>
                              <div class="p-5" id="document-editor">

                                  <div class="preview">
                                    <!-- <div class="alert alert-primary alert-dismissible show flex items-center mb-2" role="alert">
                                      <i data-feather="alert-octagon" class="w-6 h-6 mr-2"></i>{{note}}<button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"> <i data-feather="x" class="w-4 h-4"></i> </button> </div> -->
                                      <!-- <div data-editor="document" class="editor document-editor"> -->
                                        <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th></th>
                                                        <th>Server</th>
                                                        <th>Name</th>
                                                        <th>Labels</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody>
                                                    {% for datas in customerserver %}
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                          <div class="form-check form-switch">
                                                            
                                                                <input class="form-check-input" name="Servers" value="{{datas.ServerName}}" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
                                                                <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
                                                            </form>
```

So here i have to collect all checkbox values selected /(Checkbox name:Servers) , and post it in views.py , but here when i try to print it in views.py . it shows []

and here is my AJAX call :

```
$("submit").click(function(){
                             var myarray = [];
                             $(".form-check-input:checked").each(function() {
                                 myarray.push($(this).val()); //push each val into the array
                              });
                              $.ajax({
                                  url: "secondtableonDashboard", //replace with you url
                                  method: 'POST',
                                  data: myarray,
                                  enctype: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                  processData: false,
                                  contentType: false,
                                  success: function(data) {
                                      var newDoc = document.open("text/html", "replace");
                                      newDoc.write(data);
                                      newDoc.close();

                                      $('#example').hide();
                                      $('#exampleSecond').DataTable();
                                  },
                                  error: function(error) {

                                  }
                            });
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you forget to add `action="/your-name/"` into your `<form>` tag .

To fix your issue , just add `action="/your-name/"` into your `<form>` tag .

Here is an example :

```
<form action="/your-name/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
.... lots of removed....
 </form>
```

Comment: but am posting it to same page is that necessary

Comment: Yes, it is necessary .

Comment: but if i don't give anything , it will post to same page right

Comment: and even my post works fine , only my checkbox value is not getting printed

Comment: Actually when anyone click on submit button then there is a question and that is which back-end file should be execute right now . So that's why you have to tell the submit button using action=" " keyword  that it should go to  that specific file for execution . That's why all of your code should be work without action=" " keyword  but submit button should not be work without that.

Comment: yeah but still am not getting checkbox value

Comment: Sure , please , think the ajax is not posting myarray vaue

Comment: Tell me about your action=" " . I mean which URL you gave into the " " .

Comment: <form method="post" action="{% url 'secondtableonDashboard' %}">{% csrf_token %}

Comment: Check it out this link  and inform me : [LInk] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532573/ajax-post-not-sending-data-when-calling-request-post-in-django-view)