# Is there a way to JSON.stringify an object and have it's type be JSON?

Tags: json, typescript

If I do this:

```
import { MyType } from 'somewhere';

class MyClass {
    myObj: MyType = new MyType();

    updateObject(newVal: string): void {
        myObj.thing = newVal;
        this.saveStuff(JSON.stringify(myObj));
    }

    saveStuff(json: JSON): void {
        // http request...
    }
}
```

I get an error that I'm passing a string, not JSON. (I understand that I am in fact passing a string) How can I make it take the string as JSON?

I tried casting the string as JSON, ie: `JSON.stringify(foo) as JSON` or `<JSON> JSON.stringify(foo)`. But I get a "Type 'string' cannot be converted to type 'JSON'." error both ways.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this? As in: Why not mark it as string (it is after all a string)?

Comment: I want to accurately set the typings for everything. I can just set it to string, but it's really JSON, so I want it to be seen as JSON in the code.

Comment: It actually is not JSON, it is string. You are using a static method of the JSON class whose result is a string. Hence the name `stringify`.

Comment: As I stated in the question, "I understand that I am in fact passing a string". However, JSON literally *IS* a string.

Comment: JSON is a content format. Don't confuse that with the `JSON` class.

Comment: Typescript has JSON interface according to the code helper in VS Code. I assumed it was a separate thing from the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing with the TypeScript type annotation is to announce the type you *expect* a value to have (you don't *declare* the type). More often than never it happens that you set a type annotation and when you run the code you discover that the actual type is something else.

In this case though the TS compiler can evaluate the types beforehand. It *knows* that `JSON.stringify` returns a `string`. Since you have annotated the `saveStuff` method to accept a `JSON` object, it will give you a compiler error for the type mismatch.

Regardless of its content, a `string` remains a `string`. It may contain JSON, XML or a poem. It will still be nothing else than a `string`. The `JSON` class is just a utility class that provides you with a way to serialize and deserialize a JavaScript `object` into and from a `string` (with JSON content).

Answer (score 0):

`JSON` is not a type. When you parse a string by calling `JSON.parse(str)`, what you get is an object literal.

In your code, as you call `JSON.stringify(foo)`, you are converting the object literal `foo` to a string.

Thus, your `saveStuff()` receives a string.

JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation. It is just a specification on how to represent an object.

Comment: As outlined in the answers/comments on this question I posted a few years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32570523/why-when-sending-data-over-ajax-do-you-have-to-json-stringify-your-objects JSON is a string.