# AJAX send POST request to PHP backend

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

When making an AJAX POST call to PHP backend, is it not necessary to JSON.stringify the POST params/request object ?
Can it be sent directly as JS object ? What is the difference in handling the same on the PHP side?

Any best practices for the request object.

Comment: Particular answer is here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32570523/why-when-sending-data-over-ajax-do-you-have-to-json-stringify-your-objects

Answer (score 1):

1. Is it not necessary to JSON.stringify the POST params/request object?

The general answer is: an object should `aways` be serialized (eg: `JSON.stringify`) to be sent through network. But if you are using some JavaScript frameworks which can serialize an object to a JSON string (or byte stream) automatically, then you can pass your object to the framework directly and let the framework handle it.

2. Can it be sent directly as JS object?

No, any object should be serialized to a byte stream (or string) to be sent to the server side.

Here is about [What is serialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633402/what-is-serialization)

3. What is the difference in handling the same on the PHP side?

On PHP side, you just de-serialize the byte stream you received and you get the original object.

Comment: Thanks...But I am a bit confused...when you say, we can send request payload without stringifying (though we should), does it not mean it is actually possible to send without serializing ?

Comment: You should always serialize an object to send it through network. If your framework helps to serialize an object automatically, you can just pass the object to the framework.

Comment: @testndtv I never mean "we can send request payload without stringifying". updated.

Comment: Thanks. When you say "framework which can serialize an object to a JSON ", I assume you are referring to the backend framework here e.g. PHP or somethin.

Is that correct ?

Comment: There are plenty of JavaScript frameworks